# How dockerize a multi module springboot application?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dockerfile

I am new in docker. I am using maven compiler plugin with Dockerfile. My intention is dockerize all sub modules projects and parent project in a single container.
    In parent pom I have this modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>domainEmpresa</module>
    <module>businessEmpresa</module>
    <module>persistenceEmpresa</module>
    <module>rsEmpresa</module>
</modules>
<plugins>
<plugin>                                                                             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
           <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080:8080
ADD /target/cse-empresa.jar  cse-empresa.jar 
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "cse-empresa.jar"]

**I run this command sequence:**
```

1)

> mvn clean install

```
   [INFO] cse-empresa ........................... SUCCESS [  2.584 s]
    [INFO] domainEmpresa .......................... SUCCESS [ 11.736 s]
    [INFO] persistenceEmpresa .......................... SUCCESS [  1.047 s]
    [INFO] businessEmpresa .......................... SUCCESS [  2.045 s]
    [INFO] rsEmpresa ......... SUCCESS [ 14.122 s]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

2)

> docker build  -t  cse-empresa  .

```
    And show: 

    Sending build context to Docker daemon 54.86 MB
    Sending build context to Docker daemon 
    Step 0 : FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
     ---> f0400225ec4b
    Step 1 : EXPOSE 8080:8080
     ---> Using Dockerfile's EXPOSE instruction      to map host ports to container ports (ip:hostPort:containerPort) is deprecated.
          Please use -p to publish the ports.
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 54a288a723e5
```

Step 2 : ADD /target/cse-empresa.jar cse-empresa.jar
INFO[0004] target/cse-empresa.jar: no such file or directory

```
**No such file or directory?**
```

I am trying to do it in the most basic way so I am not using other plugins like spotify or docker-maven-plugin, but I need to do work, so I accept any suggestions and help

Comment: Try like below. Let me if it works, I will paste it as answer.
`ADD ./target/cse-empresa.jar  ./cse-empresa.jar 
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "./cse-empresa.jar"]`

Comment: Imran, I do like your suggestion, but resulted in the same answer: "no suck file or directory"
Is there another way to dock a multi module maven project?